# openvpn_flutter library cannot import in android native code

Tags: flutter, openvpn

I wanted to make vpn app and i found a library called [openvpn_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/openvpn_flutter). I'm trying to set up for android device by following the readme steps and found out I cannot import the library in MainActivity.

The error shows: Cannot resolve symbol 'OpenVPNFlutterPlugin'

```
import id.laskarmedia.openvpn_flutter.OpenVPNFlutterPlugin
```

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    OpenVPNFlutterPlugin.connectWhileGranted(requestCode == 24 && resultCode == RESULT_OK);
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

I had tried in both java and kotlin project and the error are the same. Did i miss out something for import the openvpn_flutter ? Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You have to open the android folder in the android studio as an andrioid project. Not as an flutter project.